# Angular2: Download xls file I've got from back-end

Tags: php, excel, angular, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using Laravel 5.1 REST API and [maatwebsite](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export) solution in order to generate an Excel file on back-end. The only thing I want - is to start downloading the file on button click.
Currently I'm sending an AJAX request via native Angular2 `Http` service and getting something like this

```
`��ࡱ�;��  ��������������������������������` ...
```

As I understand it actually returns a file, but I have to decode it in a proper way?

Is there working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service or in your component from where you are sending http request. map your response to blob. Import ResponseContentType from @angular/http. For Downloading do like this:

```
var link=document.createElement('a');
link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
link.download="District.xls";
link.click();
```

In service do like this:

```
import { Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

downloadExcel(){
      let url = 'your url/api'
      return this.http.get(url,{headers:'pass your header',responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob})
      .map(response=>response.blob())
      .catch(error=>{return Observable.throw(error)})
  }
```